# Copy a file only if it does exists in a source directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

We need to copy a file *only* if it exists in a source directory.  Right now when the command runs, even if the file doesn't exist in the source directory, it copies and creates a file in the target that's blank.  Is there a way to only copy if the SomeFile.txt from my example, exists in the source without it creating a blank file in the target directory?

The current command looks like this:

```
if exist "\\ABCdirectory\DEFdirectory\Exports\SomeFile.txt" (copy \\ABCdirectory\DEFdirectory\Exports\SomeFile.txt 
\\GHIDirectory\Prism\WellsExport\SomeFile%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt)
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: what about just running a copy command without the if? you should get an error if the file does not exist which you can check with errorlevel if needed

Answer (score 0):

Might be simpler to:

if not exist "\ABCdirectory\DEFdirectory\Exports\SomeFile.txt"  goto :exit

echo file exists. Copy commands here

:exit